# htaccess authentication via. cname

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I need a `.htaccess` rule which does not ask for a password when you come from the cname: `xxx.example.com` but I can't get it to work.

My actual `.htaccess` file looks like this:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName “Entwurf“
AuthUserFile /my/path/to/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
Allow from 11.22.33.44
Satisfy any
```

I tried this:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName “Entwurf“
AuthUserFile /my/path/to/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
Allow from 11.22.33.44
Allow from xxx.example.com
Satisfy any
```

But it still asks for the password.

I hope someone can help with it.

Comment: What version of Apache are you using?

Comment: @MrWhite I use an apache 2.4

Comment: I assume by CNAME, you are referring to the requested hostname? Otherwise, by CNAME, what are you referring to exactly? (You can't see what the DNS CNAME is here. (?))

Comment: @MrWhite Yes sorry, i meant that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By CNAME, it seems you are actually referring to the hostname that is being requested. (The hostname we are going *to*.)

So, anyone who requests `xxx.example.com` have unrestricted access OR the client with IP address `11.22.33.44`, regardless of the hostname they are requesting (assuming you are serving mutliple hostnames).

> ```
> Allow from xxx.example.com
> ```

This checks the resolved hostname of the client making the request - this is not the same thing. (In order to get the hostname here, the server is required to make a DNS lookup of the client's IP address - this is disabled on some shared servers because of the additional overhead it places on the server). For most users this simply refers to the ISP through which they are accessing the internet.

Also, `Order`, `Deny` and `Allow` directives are Apache 2.2 directives. If you are on Apache 2.4 then you should probably be using the `Require ...` directives instead. Unless you are maintaining backwards compatibility with a server that is still using the old Apache 2.2 directives (the two should not be mixed).

On Apache 2.4 you can use Apache Expressions... so only use HTTP authentication if the client's IP is not `11.22.33.44` and `xxx.example.com` is not the host being requested.

For example:

```
<If "%{HTTP_HOST} != 'xxx.example.com' && %{REMOTE_ADDR} != '11.22.33.44'">
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Entwurf"
    AuthUserFile /my/path/to/.htpasswd
    Require valid-user
</If>
```

You also appeared to be using curly quotes in the `AuthName` directive - maybe this was just a formatting issue in your question?